# How to use socks5 proxy in android app?

Tags: android, proxy, socks

The aim is to use socks5 for all connections in android app. As it said here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html, 
I just need to use system properties to set port, hostname and socks version:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost",addr);
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort",port);
System.setProperty("socksProxyVersion","5")
```

Then create a connection:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

    OutputStream output = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
    int total = 0, fileNameLength = sUrl[0].length();
    int count;
    try {
        // Download file from URL
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
        SocketAddress socketAddress;
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //Accepting all certs
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }
                }
        };

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return s.equals(sslSession.getPeerHost());
            }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        connection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

        input = connection.getInputStream();
```

But when I sniffer traffic, it always uses socks4. Http, Https proxies work as expected. Then I tryed to find out which type of socket creates, if I call Socket constructor with a proxy specified directly:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(proxyAddr, proxyPort)));
Class clazzSocks  = socket.getClass();
Method setSockVersion  = null;
Field sockImplField = null;
SocketImpl socksimpl = null;
sockImplField = clazzSocks.getDeclaredField("impl");
sockImplField.setAccessible(true);
socksimpl  = (SocketImpl) sockImplField.get(socket);
Class clazzSocksImpl  =  socksimpl.getClass();
```

And it shows that clazzSocksImpl is PlainSocketImpl instead of SocksSocketImpl that I expected. Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is small example which demonstrate the implementation of socks5 in android

https://github.com/heiher/hev-htproxy